# Unificar 2 registros en 1 - SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos días,

Tengo 2 registros que son casi idénticos, donde solo difieren en 1 columna.

Lo que necesitaría hacer es tener un solo registro con los campos que difieren.

En la imagen lo que tengo (Los dos registros de arriba) y lo que necesito (Un solo registro con toda la info de ambos registros sin repetir).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria toda idea que aporte a una solucion.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: "Lo que necesitaría hacer es tener un solo registro con los campos que difieren" pero no estas mostrando eso en tu segundo dibujo? a que queres llegar con esto, porque capaz hay una solucion mejor?

Comment: Hola Oksy. ¿Qué has intentado? Además, debes explicar claramente la lógica. ¿Cuándo califica un registro para ser unido a otro registro? Y cuando esto sucede, cómo escoges el valor que quieres para la(s) columna(s) donde sí hay diferencias de valores. Y qué hay si tienes más de 2 registros que se parecen, etc..

Comment: qué resultado querrías si la segunda fila fuera: `g,b,h,i,j,k`?. Siempre son sólo 2 filas?

Comment: Buenas tardes gbianchi, sstan, lo que obtengo hoy, es dos registros donde la ultima columna puede venir cualquier valor, entonces quiero solo obtener 1 solo registro y los diferentes valores hacerlos columna. Es es lo que se refleja en la imagen, los campos comunes no los repito y los diferentes los hago columna. Eso es todo, no hay mas logica que esa. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si Lamark, solo viene 2 registros, siempre.

Comment: necesitamos saber si los datos diferentes son siempre en la última columna o puede pasar en columnas anteriores....y en ese caso, cuál sería el resultado que buscas?

Comment: Siempre es la ultima columna, donde en un registro viene el email y en el otro registro viene el nombre y el apellido, siempre. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Intento agruparlo por la ultima columna, pero como no tengo campos calculados no me permite agruparlos. Intente utilizar PIVOT, pero no me sirve para esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, si siempre son sólo 2 filas de datos, y el dato diferente siempre es en la última columna, entonces puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        MIN(col5) col5,
        MAX(col5) col6
FROM dbo.TuTabla
GROUP BY col1,
         col2,
         col3,
         col4
;
```

Ahora, de esta forma no vas a saber de antemano en cuál columna está el email y en cuál el nombre. Para esto, podrías usar el siguiente código:

```
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN col5 LIKE '%@%' THEN col5 END) col5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN col5 NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN col5 END) col6
FROM dbo.TuTabla
GROUP BY col1,
         col2,
         col3,
         col4
;
```

Comment: Mil Gracias Lamak, es lo que necesitaba!!!